# Which is the best constructor of unordered_map to replace one old project defined class UtilHashTable

Tags: c++, constructor, stl, unordered-map

In our base code, we are trying to replace one project defined class UtilHashTable by unordered_map to improve performance. 
C'tor of UtilHashTable looks like:

```
template< class Key, class Val, class Hash >
UtilHashTable< Key, Val, Hash >::UtilHashTable( unsigned inInitialBuckets,
                                                unsigned inMaxProbes ) :
  cMaxProbes( inMaxProbes )
{
  cLoadFactor = 0.5;
  mSize = 0;
  unsigned size = 1;
  while( inInitialBuckets > 0 )
  {
    size <<= 1;
    inInitialBuckets >>= 1;
  }
  //mTable = new vector< Entry >( size );
  mTable = new unordered_map< Key, Val >( size );
  mNumRehashes = 0;
  mNumLookups = 0;
  mNumProbes = 0;
  mHashMask = static_cast< uint32>( mTable->size() - 1 );
}
```

In the header file, its declaration looks like:

```
UtilHashTable( unsigned inInitialBuckets = 500, unsigned inMaxProbes = 40 );
```

We are providing flexibility to the user to set `InitialBuckets` and `MaxProbes` if they want!

Please suggest me which c'tor of unordered_map will work best to replace everything inside the c'tor of UtilHashTable.

Tell me if you need any further info.
Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: I don't think stdlib lets you choose those values. Why do you need them, anyway?

Comment: Did you look at the [unordered_map reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)? There is a constructor overload that takes a `bucket_count` parameter, but there is nothing like your `inMaxProbes`.